# Scenario questions for JWT

Tags: jwt

My site has several sub-domains:

1. Authentication provider
2. Ajax API for web site
3. API for mobile app
4. Public API

For #2-3, I'd like to redirect user to auth provider domain to login and return a JWT back to the client. A few questions I have regarding secure and customary usage:

1. I'd like to limit scope of what token can do, and I see on the web that is a standard for token-based authentication. My question is: Is it customary and secure for the caller to request the scope list, and the auth provider just returns it? It's not really like 3rd party OAUTH where the auth provider asks the user. I'd like this to all happen silently. I guess it's more secure than not using scope at all, because if theoretically the token is compromised, then at least it's usability is limited.
2. Similar to question # 1, is it customary and secure for caller to request an expiration date and for provider to adhere to that request? The alternative would be for provider to make its own decision.

Answer (score 1):

1. OAuth 2.0 is what you're looking for; the granted scopes when users are not involved depend on the implementation at the Authorization Server; e.g. if you use a "client credentials" grant, the client would have to be pre-registered with the Authorization Server and the allowed scopes could be registered as a part of that
2. it is not defined in the spec how to do that in a standardized way; the provider makes its own decision and again this could be part of configuration settings for a pre-registered client; there is an alternative: some OAuth 2.0 flows (not client credentials though) have the option to return a refresh token as well which can be used to extend the expiry time of access by requesting a new token; to limit the expiry time of access a client can explicitly revoke an access token if the Authorization Server supports [RFC 7009](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009)